# Locating an element on Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I was looking for a solution for this problem. 
I cant get the element of user email field. I've tried with wait for the element, page factory, and another solutions, but nothing worked for me, Selenium still throwing two errors:

```
 the element is not visible OR stable element problem.
```

If somebody could help me i think its easier doing it directly trying on the [original page](http://tmpangular.theamalgama.com/#/landing/register)

thank you so much.

CLASSES:

```
public class LoginPageWithFactory {
        WebDriver driver;

        @FindBy(xpath= "//input[@type='email']")
        WebElement userNameField;

 @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='password']")
    WebElement passwordField;

    @FindBy(id = "btn-login")
    WebElement loginButton;

    public LoginPageWithFactory(WebDriver pDriver) {
        this.driver = pDriver;
        AjaxElementLocatorFactory factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver,100);
        PageFactory.initElements(factory, this);
        //PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    public void writeUserName(String username) {
        userNameField.sendKeys(username);
    }
    public void writePassword(String password){
        passwordField.sendKeys(password);
    }
    public void clickOnLogin(){
        loginButton.click();
    }
}

public class LoginTestCases {
    WebDriver webDriver;
    LandingPage landingPage;
    LoginPageWithFactory loginPage;

    public LoginTestCases(){
        webDriver = new StartDriver("http://tmpangular.theamalgama.com").getWebDriver();
        landingPage = new LandingPage(webDriver);
    }
    @Test
    public void successfulLogin(){
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
        landingPage.goToLoginPage();
        loginPage = new LoginPageWithFactory(webDriver);
        loginPage.writeUserName("julieta@theamalgama.com");
        loginPage.writePassword("sinclair");
        loginPage.clickOnLogin();
    }
}

public class LandingPage {
    WebDriver driver;
    By loginButton = By.id("btn-header-login");
    By registerButton = By.id("btn-get-started");

    public LandingPage(WebDriver mdriver){
        this.driver = mdriver;
    }

    public void goToLoginPage(){
        driver.findElement(loginButton).click();
    }

    public void goToCreateNewAccount(){
        driver.findElement(registerButton).click();
    }
}

public class StartDriver {

    WebDriver webDriver;

    public StartDriver(String url){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/julieta/Apps/IntelliJ Idea/chromedriver");
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.navigate().to(url);
        webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return webDriver;
    }
}
```

ERROR

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:/home/julieta/Apps/IntelliJ Idea/lib/idea_rt.jar=34246:/home/julieta/Apps/IntelliJ Idea/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/home/julieta/Apps/IntelliJ Idea/lib/idea_rt.jar:/home/julieta/Apps/IntelliJ Idea/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/home/julieta/Apps/IntelliJ Idea/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/julieta/workspace/tmp Automated Test/out/production/tmp Automated Test:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/client-combined-3.4.0-nodeps.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/sac-1.3.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/gson-2.8.0.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/guava-21.0.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/junit-4.12.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/xalan-2.7.2.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/htmlunit-2.26.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/httpcore-4.4.6.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/httpmime-4.5.3.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/commons-exec-1.3.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/cssparser-0.9.22.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/httpclient-4.5.3.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/neko-htmlunit-2.25.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/htmlunit-driver-2.26.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/htmlunit-core-js-2.26.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/phantomjsdriver-1.4.0.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/jetty-io-9.4.1.v20170120.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/jetty-util-9.4.1.v20170120.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/websocket-api-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/websocket-client-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenium/selenium-java-3.4.0/lib/websocket-common-9.4.3.v20170317.jar:/home/julieta/Documents/librerias selenium appium/selenide-4.5.1.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 Test.LoginTestCases
```

Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57) on port 9472
Only local connections are allowed.
Jul 21, 2017 1:51:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57),platform=Linux 4.4.0-79-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.32 seconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'julieta-comp', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-79-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.30.477691 (6ee44a7247c639c0703f291d320bdf05c1531b57), userDataDir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.lDUW7C}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=LINUX, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 420607562e9c49a3d9a03809a02731a6

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:51)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.sendKeys(Unknown Source)
at PageObject.LoginPageWithFactory.writeUserName(LoginPageWithFactory.java:28)
at Test.LoginTestCases.successfulLogin(LoginTestCases.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: Can you post your code and errors that you are seeing?

Comment: @smit9234 thank u for the recomendation, ive edited my post.

Comment: Did you just post a real password to a public forum?

Comment: @SiKing jaja thank u, i did not get realize

Comment: Error stack trace says `ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)` is pretty much at the beginning. Can you consider to reduce your code please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

In `LoginPageWithFactory` Class, to identify the `Email` field, the `xpath` which you have provided i.e. `//input[@type='email']` is not unique. You can consider the following line of code which identify the `Email` field:

```
@FindBy(xpath= "//form[@id='log-in-form']/input[@type='email']")
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @JulietaMoraleda Glad to be able to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be a variety of things.

1. The Element is not in your viewport

You can solve that like this:

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

2. Try searching by the xpath

Sometimes theres multiple elements under the same property your trying to search and your just using the wrong one. You can get the xpath through inspect elements on google chrome or any other web browser.

3. Most likely the element is not loaded yet

you can use implicit wait to make sure the element is loaded:

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

Comment: thank u for your recomendatios, ive tried some of this things, but ive forget to upload the driver class, Im gonna to upload it now, if you can check it -